# How to get the thumbnail url for a video in an Instagram hashtag feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

This is specifically about hashtags using the Facebook Instagram API.

Has anyone successfully retrieved the thumbnail url for a video in a hashtag feed? Even when using the graph API I cannot get anything to return?

[image]

Comment: Field name for that should be `thumbnail_url`, according to docs. Did you try that?

Comment: thumbnail_url does not work according to hashtag recent media or top media. When you add that edge an error stating that option is not available appears. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/recent-media https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/top-media

Comment: What happens when you go directly via the video ID you get returned from those endpoints, are you able to request the field then?

Comment: Tried that too and I get a permissions issue. Crazy this has not been addressed after a year even. I have dropped notes to the devs at facebook and they won't to address this issue. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/447131569212308/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the thumbnail_url you have to make an **extra** call to the Oembed endpoint using the post for the video and an access token. You must have an approved APP for this to work also. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed/

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/instagram_oembed?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/CKRgKXoif40/&access_token=xxxxxx
```

Then you will see the thumbnail_url option available to you.
[image]